# Excel data table into calendar view

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Excel Sample Screenshot]

As per the example screenshot, I have a table with a number of orders for each team over certain a number of months depending on the start date. I am looking for a way to display it in a calendar view to workout the peak periods...etc
Any suggestions on the best way to do it?

Comment: Not very clearly, What kind of calendar did you have? The screenshot table 2?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get your first badge

Comment: yes, the second table